# Graph execution error having InvalidArgumentError during model.fit() in tensorflow token classification problem

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, kaggle, huggingface-datasets

I'm working on a Token classification problem for this kaggle competition (https://www.kaggle.com/code/tdutta7/jargondetection) for which I have loaded a dataset in huggingface (https://huggingface.co/datasets/Tauhait/JargonDetection).

I'm trying to build a model based on distilbert-base-uncased.

Error is happening during model fit :

```
model.fit(x=tf_train_set, validation_data=tf_validation_set, epochs=3, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Error stacktrace:

```
Epoch 1/3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-abda515b1691> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(x=tf_train_set, validation_data=tf_validation_set, epochs=3, callbacks=callbacks)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50   try:
     51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 267, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 642, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/utils/tf_utils.py", line 104, in np_get_batch
    batch = collate_fn(batch, **collate_fn_args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py", line 43, in __call__
    return self.tf_call(features)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py", line 369, in tf_call
    batch = {k: tf.convert_to_tensor(v, dtype=tf.int64) for k, v in batch.items()}

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py", line 369, in <dictcomp>
    batch = {k: tf.convert_to_tensor(v, dtype=tf.int64) for k, v in batch.items()}

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 103, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[IteratorGetNext/_4]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 267, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 642, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/utils/tf_utils.py", line 104, in np_get_batch
    batch = collate_fn(batch, **collate_fn_args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py", line 43, in __call__
    return self.tf_call(features)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py", line 369, in tf_call
    batch = {k: tf.convert_to_tensor(v, dtype=tf.int64) for k, v in batch.items()}

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py", line 369, in <dictcomp>
    batch = {k: tf.convert_to_tensor(v, dtype=tf.int64) for k, v in batch.items()}

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 103, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_18820]
```

Notebook link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19TeQBJgnt-0Chtkn-4vKIWGHHM8rIqnQ?usp=sharing